# importing the package net.jodah.typetools, unsafe types/methods isn't working (assuming because of missmatched java version)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods, java-8

The error I'm getting in eclipse:

Access restriction: The method Unsafe.{the methods} is not API (restriction from required library '{path to jdk1.8.0_291}/jre/lib/rt.jar')

and

Access restriction: The Type Unsafe is not API. (restriction from required library '{path to jdk1.8.0_291}/jre/lib/rt.jar')

Using JDK 8, for an old version of a game I'm modding. Any answers are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `Unsafe` accessible by defining an access rule.

Open the project "Properties" and go to the "Libraries" page.

Expand the "JRE System Library" section in the list and you should be able to select an "Access Rules" entry.

Click the "Edit..." button to define a new access rules. Enter the rule:

```
sun/misc/Unsafe
```

to allow Unsafe.

You should end up with something like:
[image: Build Path]